Person of interest/under investigation living abroad - what can the UK police do?
If the UK police suspect someone may have been involved in a serious crime, but don't have enough evidence for an arrest, they would presumably want to interview that person. But they can't find out where he is, so the case is put on hold. Some years later, they find out that he is living abroad at a certain address in a country about 12 hours flying time from the UK. What can/would the police do? Send an officer to that country to interview the person? Ask local police to interview the person? Ask local police if the person has been involved in any criminal activity? Anything else?

What could the police do? Any of these things.
Countries sometimes send a police officer as an attache to their diplomatic mission in another country. Here's an example of an announcement of a Lithuanian police attache being sent to the UK. Part of their responsibilities would be coordinating the law enforcement between the countries, and handling cases of this type.
In some cases countries send a police delegation, that would, with cooperation of the local law enforcement, conduct investigative actions there. Here's an example of a Dutch-Israeli joint criminal investigation in Holland. An accused rapist was arrested by the Dutch police based on the Israeli warrants, and with the on-the-ground support from the Israeli police (who identified the suspect).
What would the police do? Who knows...

Who knows indeed? However, I would guess that it would be too expensive and the outcome too uncertain to send an officer all that way - fare, hotel, per diem for who knows how many days? If the person wasn't at home when the officer knocked on his door, maybe his girl friend or someone else would call him and then he'd stay away for a while. If I was in charge of the case, I'd contact the local police.

That's not how any of this works though... As the references show this is done, and done quite often and routinely. There are extradition agreements, cooperation agreements, mutual aid agreements, and what's not.

@shawn22 I don't think that costs really are the problem. The problem is jurisdiction - you simply can't go and interview a person in a foreign country unannounced, and if you already have to work with local police you may as well ask them to do the basic groundwork.

I think, without being an expert by any means, that xLeitix must be right in this case. Extradition agreements are irrelevant if the police only want to question the person and there's no arrest warrant.

@shawn22 yes, that's exactly what I wrote in the answer. The point xLeitix makes is that the police cannot go unannounced to another country (although, it can, really, just try not to get caught by the local leos - see for example the extraction of Adolf Eichmann from Argentina). But it most definitely can go announced.
